# Get an Activity in a Adapter - Android studio in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a newbie developer, I'm trying to use Heyzap / Fyber Ads mediation, and I need some help with this:

I have an Adapter class (that isn't an Activity) used for a RecyclerView.

I've been using `view.getContext()` on many places for the context, but now it asks for "Activity"

This Adapter class contains two `OnClickListeners` where i need to insert this:

```
InterstitialAd.display(// I need to insert "Activity" here);
```

I've been tried with:

```
this
Activity.this (constructor & adapter)
Activity.class (constructor & adapter)
view.getActivity()


///And 999x other combinations.
```

Comment: Try this `((Activity)context)`. And pass Activity context using Constructor of Adapter

Comment: It worked! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to have an interface for communication with the activity. This way you can shift all the code concerning the view "onClick" to the activity/fragment layer itself where they should be IMO.

Here is a tutorial around the same https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9

Answer (score 0):

A context can be an activity, so you could cast it. Even better, test it first to make sure it's an activity and then cast it. You could create a helper method to do the work for you:

```
private static Activity getActivity(View view) {
    if (view.getContext() instanceof Activity) {
        return (Activity)view.getContext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: and then will be

``` 
InterstitialAd.display(getActivity(View));
````
No?

I think it worked like this

Thank you !

Comment: basically yeah. wherever you have a view and need to get an activity, you can use this helper method.

Comment: Okey!  Thank you!!